# Pandoc: is it possible to disable interpretation of inline HTML in markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, inline, pandoc

I need markdown only for what options its syntax offers.

So I don't want it to interpret inline HTML (e.g. `<span>hello</span>`), but it should display those tags as text.

Is there a way to disable this? Or should I simply search and replace each and every `<` and `>` with a `&lt;` and `&gt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call pandoc with `-f markdown-raw_html`, i.e., disable the [`raw_html`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_html) extension.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.